# Firestore Invalid Permissions: request.auth.uid in

Tags: firebase, firebase-security, google-cloud-firestore

I am using Cloud Firestore and I can't seem to get the "IN" operator to work with the security rules. I have tried using array and map but neither work. Of course when I set it to  `allow read, write;` it works fine. What am I doing wrong?

Rules:

```
service cloud.firestore {
  match /databases/{database}/documents {
    match /rooms/{roomId=**} { 
      allow read, write: if request.auth.uid in resource.data.users;
      allow read, write: if request.auth.uid in resource.data.users2;
      allow create: if request.auth != null;
    }
    match /user-rooms/{userId} { 
      allow read, write: if userId == request.auth.uid;
    }
    match /users/{userId} {
      allow read, write: if request.auth.uid == userId;
      allow get, create: if request.auth != null;
    }
  }
}
```

Client:

```
db.collection("rooms")
  .document(self.room.getRoomId())
  .collection("messages")
  .addSnapshotListener { .....

//Room is: d6l946swspNSouANzVdZ
//Username is: eX8gkxJNDREv
```

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`data` will return it's direct children not it's sub-children(users and users2) so you should use `get` and `exists` instead of `in`

```
match /rooms/{roomId=**} { 
  allow read, write: if request.auth.uid in get(/databases/$(database)/documents/rooms/$(roomId)/users/$(request.auth.uid)).data;
  allow read, write: if exists(/databases/$(database)/documents/rooms/$(roomId)/users2/$(request.auth.uid));
  allow create: if request.auth != null;
}
```

checkout the [doc](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/reference/security/#service_defined)

Comment: Are you saying that the array values of users and users2 are the sub-children? As opposed to a raw string? So if I was only ever going to have two possible users to authenticate I could just do `resource.data.fromUser == request.auth.uid || resource.data.toUser == request.auth.uid` (without needing to cause a read on the database by utilizing `get()`)?

Comment: For my previous comment, no. It seems the only method that works is using `get()` to fetch `resource.data`. I don't understand this limitation for Firestore...

Answer (score 2):

You're trying to access a variable named "users" inside `resource.data` which doesn't exist. The [resource](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/reference/security/#firestore-resource) variable contains data from the object that is currently being written to the database.

What you're probably trying to do is check if this users exist in the fields `users` and `users2`, which can be achieved with the rules:

```
match /rooms/{roomId=**}{
    allow read, write:  if (exists(/databases/$(database)/documents/rooms/$(roomId)/users2/$(request.auth.uid)) || 
                         request.auth.uid in get(/databases/$(database)/documents/rooms/$(roomId)).data.users);
    allow create: if request.auth!=null;
}
```

Comment: Ok that works but I'm sorry this still doens't make sense to me. "The resource represents a Cloud Firestore document. It contains a map of the fields and values **stored** in a document in `resource.data`." The docs make it seem as if `request.resource.data` is the data being written and `resource.data` is what is already stored in the firestore database. At least that's how I interpret the docs. It doesn't make sense why I have to `get()` a resource that Firestore db should already have (from it's internal query).

Comment: Your understanding is correct. `resource.data` is what is already stored (if you're updating the data). If you're not updating existing data, it will not exist.

Comment: Look at my screenshot, the data is already there! ... Unless you're saying that a write does not perform a read first and thus resource.data is empty? EDIT: No actually that can't be the case. I'm trying to read the data in my tests. EDIT2: So are you saying that `resource.data` is null on any read operations?

Comment: Let's say you have a document named user on your database. With a name field (let's say its value is "Ryan"). Then you want to update this field to become "Rosario". `request.resource.data` will contain "Rosario" and `resource.data` will contain "Ryan". It only contains data about the field being updated/written and nothing else outside this field.

Comment: So are you saying that resource.data is null on any read operations? Because I'm looking at [docs](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/reference/security/#firestore-resource) and `allow read: if resource.data.keys().hasAll(['name', 'age'])` clearly implies that a read operation does populate `resource.data` in which I should be able to do some validation on the data without having to fetch the resource with `get()`. Or no?

Comment: Oops, I see. I guess I was wrong when I said t was null. My bad

Comment: @[Ali](https://stackoverflow.com/users/5136659/ali), is this what you were referring to with sub-children? ^ The keys are there but not the values?