# Firestore security rule get() is not working when performing a query against multiple docs

Tags: javascript, firebase, google-cloud-firestore, firebase-security

I'm having an issue when i try to access some documents. It says i don't have permission for accessing the docuemnt. So I have the following in the Firestore rules

```
match /reservations/reservations-request/list/{reservationInfo} {
  allow read: if get(/databases/$(database)/documents/reservations/reservations-request/list/$(reservationInfo)/members-id/data).data.driverId == request.auth.uid || 
  get(/databases/$(database)/documents/reservations/reservations-request/list/$(reservationInfo)/members-id/data).driverId == request.auth.uid;
  allow write: if false;
}
```

In the simulator, when i use the same uid and phone number as i use in my application, it says that i'm allowed to get a document with this path. However, when i try to do the same thing in the application (with same user uid and phone number), it doesn't allows me to access documents. The code where i try to access the documents is this one:

```
fetchReservationsAsDriver(type: string, driverId: string): Promise < any > {
    var size = 0;
    var reservations: ReservationDB[] = [];
    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
      let reservation_aux;
      firebase.firestore().collection('reservations').doc("reservations-requested").collection('list').where("driver.id", "==", driverId).get().then(function (array) {
          size = array.size;
          if (size == 0) {
            resolve(reservations);
          }
          array.forEach(function (doc) {
            reservation_aux = doc.data();
            reservations.push(reservation_aux);
            console.log(doc.id, " => ", doc.data());
          });
          resolve(reservations);
        })
        .catch(function (error) {
          console.log("Error getting documents: ", error);
          reject(error);
        });
    });
}
```

Thanks for helping!

**--------- EDIT ----------**

I figured out what is exactly the problem:

if i have this:

```
match /reservations/requested-reservations/list/{reservationInfo} {
      allow read: if get(/databases/$(database)/documents/reservations/requested-reservations/list/$(reservationInfo)/members-id/data).data.driverId == request.auth.uid
}
```

firestore rules doesn't allows me to get any document from the collection "list", but, i figured out that if change for that rule:

```
match /reservations/requested-reservations/list/{reservationInfo} {
      allow read: if get(/databases/$(database)/documents/reservations/requested-reservations/list/IYB0710-2018-06-13-1528922084314/members-id/data).data.driverId == request.auth.uid
}
```

firebase allows me to read the document (at least the document named "IYB0710-2018-06-13-1528922084314", which is one of the documents from the "list" collection).

This means that what is actually happening is that he is not replacing $(reservationInfo) with the documents name when i try to get a group of documents with this command from my application:

```
firebase.firestore().collection('reservations').doc(type).collection('list').where("driver.id", "==", driverId).get().then(function (array) {
    // Do Something
})
```

Comment: I have experienced the same. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54741364/firebase-firestore-security-rules-variable-not-used. Weird is that it seems to work on other users according to this. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48496288/firestore-invalid-permissions-request-auth-uid-in

Comment: I think this issue might be related to the 10 `get` calls limit described here: https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/security/rules-structure#security_rule_limits. When querying a large collection the rule needs to effectively call get for each document.