# Firebase Firestore Security Rules Variable not used

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-firestore, firebase-security

Writing rules for Firestore it seems that custom variables are not working.
Did anyone know why or have seen similar behaviour?
Using the below I got access denied although the uid is in the array of admin.

```
service cloud.firestore {
      match /databases/{database}/documents {
        match /conferences/{confid} {
          allow read,write: if request.auth.uid in get(/databases/$(database)/documents/conferences/$(confid)).data.admin;
        }
      }
    }
```

Simulator is giving the below error:

Function [get] called with path to nonexistent resource: /databases/%28default%29/documents/conferences/%7Bconfid%7D

Also testing this on a real devices I got access denied.

If however I use the ID of the document like below it works and access is granted.

```
service cloud.firestore {
  match /databases/{database}/documents {
    match /conferences/{confid} {
      allow read,write: if request.auth.uid in get(/databases/$(database)/documents/conferences/ySWLb8NSTj9sur6n2CbS).data.admin;
    }
  }
}
```

Obviously I can't hardcode this for each and every ID.

**UPDATE**

Apart from logging the case with support I have done some further testing.
On the below the simulator is now granting access.

```
service cloud.firestore {
  match /databases/{database}/documents {
    match /conferences/{confID}{
      allow read, write: if request.auth.uid in get(/databases/$(database)/documents/conferences/$(confID)/permissions/permission).data.users;
        }
  }
}
```

[image: Simulator]

For reference I use the below to query from my web-application:

```
db.collection("conferences")
  .get()
  .then(query => {
    console.log("SUCCESS!!!")
    query.forEach(function(doc) {
      // doc.data() is never undefined for query doc snapshots
      console.log(doc.id, " => ", doc.data());
    });
  }).catch((e) => {
    console.log(e)
  })
```

This is the log from the browser:

FirebaseError: Missing or insufficient permissions.
    at new FirestoreError (webpack-internal:///./node_modules/@firebase/firestore/dist/index.cjs.js:352:28)
    at JsonProtoSerializer.fromRpcStatus (webpack-internal:///./node_modules/@firebase/firestore/dist/index.cjs.js:5649:16)
    at JsonProtoSerializer.fromWatchChange (webpack-internal:///./node_modules/@firebase/firestore/dist/index.cjs.js:6146:44)
    at PersistentListenStream.onMessage (webpack-internal:///./node_modules/@firebase/firestore/dist/index.cjs.js:14350:43)
    at eval (webpack-internal:///./node_modules/@firebase/firestore/dist/index.cjs.js:14279:30)
    at eval (webpack-internal:///./node_modules/@firebase/firestore/dist/index.cjs.js:14319:28)
    at eval (webpack-internal:///./node_modules/@firebase/firestore/dist/index.cjs.js:7411:20)

I am using the latest Firebase package 5.8.3.

If I change the above rule to something simple like below it got access as long as I am logged in with a user:

```
service cloud.firestore {
  match /databases/{database}/documents {
    match /conferences/{confID}{
      allow read, write: if request.auth.uid != null
        }
  }
}
```

This even confuses me more. Is this because the rule is more complex and it takes too long to get this verified and gives back access denied?

**Update-2**

Quickly tested this in a mobile app via Flutter. Same result. Access denied with this ruleset.

```
service cloud.firestore {
  match /databases/{database}/documents {
    match /conferences/{confID}{
      allow read, write: if request.auth.uid in get(/databases/$(database)/documents/conferences/$(confID)/permissions/permission).data.users;
        }
  }
}
```

[image: Firestore]

Comment: I've never had a problem using variables before. It's definitely not broken in a general sense.

Comment: Glad to hear it is not broken overall. But I am a bit stuck here with troubleshooting. Any advise on the posted rules?

Comment: Seems another user experienced the same which is also not resolved. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50825365/firestore-security-rule-get-is-not-working-when-performing-a-query-against-mul

Comment: If you think it's broken, contact Firebase support, as Stack Overflow will not likely be of help to you.  https://firebase.google.com/support/contact/

Comment: Opened a case of course. Curious what support will advise.

Answer (score 0):

I think my problem was the query's don't match security rules. If you would only access a single specific document it would work but if you query multiple documents in a collection you got blocked by the security rules.
I had two options. Restructure my data so that a single document will hold all the data I need or redesign security rules to match query's.
In the end I have attached to each document an indentifier like the UID to make sure query's match the security rules.

Answer (score 0):

One solution would be to put the users with permissions into an array in the conference document instead,
so `request.resource.data.permissions`

So, instead of this:

```
get(/databases/$(database)/documents/conferences/$(confID)/permissions/permission).data.users
```

use this:

```
request.resource.data.permissions
```

This wouldn't solve the `get()` problem, but it would eliminate the need for a `get()` call, which could save you 15% or more on your quota.